# iOS Resize and crop not squared images - high quality

Tags: ios, uiimage, resize, crop

I'm facing the following problem : I have several UIImage (not squared) and I need to resize and crop them. I have read almost every question on StackOverflow but the results that I get are not good, I mean the image produced has a poor quality(blurry).
This is the scenario :
1) Original images size : width 208 pixel  - height variable (i.e. from 50 to 2500)
2) Result images        : width 100 pixel  - height max 200 pixel

That is what I've done so far to achieve this result :

```
..... // missing code
CGFloat height = (100*image.size.height)/image.size.width;
self.thumbnail=[image resizedImage:CGSizeMake(100,height) 
              interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh];

..... // missing code
```

The method that I use to resize the image can be found [here](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/) , once the image is resized I crop it using the following code :

```
CGRect croppedRect;
croppedRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.thumbnail.size.width, 200);  
CGImageRef tmp = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([self.thumbnail CGImage], 
                                                          croppedRect);
self.thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:tmp];
CGImageRelease(tmp);
```

Long story short, the image is resized and cropped but the quality is really poor considering that the original image had a really good quality.
So the question is how to achieve this keeping an high quality of the image?

Answer (score 1):

If you target iOS 4 and later you should use ImageIO to resize images.

http://www.cocoabyss.com/coding-practice/uiimage-scaling-using-imageio/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've read your post (really nice job), but probably because of my lack of experience, the result that I get using ImageIO are the worst :( .... basically what I did is to initialize a CGImageSource with the image that I want to resize, I have used the same option dictionary that you use in your example, changing the value for maxSize ( first doubt just one value ?? ) and  I have created a thumbnail from the source, but as I said the images are extremely blurry. One thing that I do not understand is how do you specify the dimension for the thumbnail?

Comment: You the specify the biggest size, in your case the height, and the image will be scaled to fit this maximum size.